# Android: Raise a toolbar on button click (Like in the facebook official app)

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to show a popup menu when a user clicks a button. The popup should shown on the left side on the button clicked. Just like when you click the "plus" sign on a post in the official Facebook app (raises a like/comment buttons).

How did Facebook implemented this? This is not a regular popup activity.. seems to me it's a view inflated by the main activity on a specific location ..

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at Android's [`SlidingDrawer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html). I think it is exactly what you need to implement such a functionality.

Comment: SlidingDrawer changes my view.. i want to open the toolbar on top of the view.